# Background image won't show on only on iPhone devices

Tags: html, css, iphone, spring-boot-starter

I'm working on a website and it's nearly finished, I've solved a lot of problems using this StackOverflow, so thank you very much. But I failed to find a solution to this problem. So the problem is that the background image of the intro website won't show on iPhone devices (Desktop, Samsung, Android etc. works). So does anyone know why this problem occurs only on iPhone devices and how to solve it?

Website link: http://cubedesign.ba/

The code is long, so I don't know what to really send.

Comment: Which image won't show on iPhone? I can't see any difference between the desktop and iPhone versions

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/fSTqWT/bg.jpg this. It's the intro image. It's weird, it even works on Apple desktop devices, but mobile devices won't show it. iPhone: https://scontent.fsjj1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/33367577_1712549152116351_431137458646679552_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=3d465d91de3e5f8c239e281a09c7b8f5&oe=5BC0B808

Comment: It shows up on my iPhone, I suspect the file size might be a little large and maybe your device isn't able to load it.